# How to insert a const std::shared_ptr into a std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::shared_ptr<const std::string> ConstDataTypePtr;
typedef std::map<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr> StrDataTypeMap;

int main()
{
    StrDataTypeMap m_nameToType;
    ConstDataTypePtr vp_int8(new std::string("RGH"));
    m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>("int8_t", vp_int8));
    return 0;
}
```

You must compile it with: `g++ -std=c++11 <filename>.cpp`.

It gives the following error:

```
    testO.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testO.cpp:14:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(const char [7], ConstDataTypePtr&)’
     m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>("int8_t", vp_int8));
                                                                                        ^
testO.cpp:14:88: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:40,
                 from testO.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testO.cpp:14:88: note:   cannot convert ‘vp_int8’ (type ‘ConstDataTypePtr {aka std::shared_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> >}’) to type ‘std::shared_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> >&&’
     m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>("int8_t", vp_int8));
```

From what I am reading of the error, the compiler is expecting an r-value when I am trying to insert into the map. Why? What mistake have I made here?

Kindly note that I created this snippet from some existing code which is part of a large code-base. It is probably also worth mentioning that the snippet has been taken from a code base which was run on Windows and I have the task of porting it to Linux. The original author had used std::tr1::shared_ptr. I modified it to use std::shared_ptr. I didn't expect any repercussions because of this change.

Comment: The whole point of `std::make_pair` is to let compiler deduce types. If you want to provide type, use `std::pair<K, V>`.

Comment: In the future, please post [MCVE]s that actually reproduce the exact problem you are having.  Editing your question after people provide solutions to your problem to change it to a new question is bad form.  And @PatrykWertka managed to solve your problem prior to your edit, but you proceeded to edit your question to have a *different* problem, which PatrykWertka's solution *still* solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of `std::make_pair` is to let compiler deduce types. If you want to provide type, use `std::pair<K, V>`

So

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("int8_t", vp_int8));
```

should be:

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair("int8_t", vp_int8));
```

or

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::pair<const std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>("int8_t", vp_int8));
```

or simply:

```
m_nameToType.emplace("int8_t", vp_int8);
```

Comment: `std::make_pair` should have a defaulted first template type argument called `class stop_passing_arguments_to_me = I_am_not_kidding` with a `static_assert( std::is_same<stop_passing_arguments_to_me, I_am_not_kidding>::value, "do not supply type arguments to std::make_pair manually.  If you want to do that, please just use std::pair directly.  You are using me wrong." );`  But maybe that would be too subtle.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, the sarcasm is very well done here; but someone better could have explained *why* passing type arguments gives that exact error.

Comment: @wild It is probably unspecified behaviour, but the particular error is because of a failure of perfect forwarding.  By passing `X` as a type, the arg is `X&&`, an rvalue, and you passed an lvalue.  The above comment is because this `make_pair` error is depressingly common.  It was probably introduced because you went from a copy-only to a move-capable make_pair, as a guess.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using shared_data = std::shared_ptr<const std::string>;

    std::map<std::string, shared_data> map;
    map.insert(std::make_pair(
        "something", 
        shared_data(new std::string("something else"))
    ));
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/4AQfqd

Back to your problem;

> testO.cpp:14:83: note:   cannot convert ‘vp_int8’ (type ‘ConstDataTypePtr {aka std::shared_ptr >}’) to type ‘std::basic_string&&’
>        m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair("int8_t", vp_int8));

What you have:

```
std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>(some_string, TOTALLY_NOT_A_STRING)
```

Comment: You are correct. Earlier I was using the wrong type. Could you please look at the question again? (I have updated it). Still I am getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

You gave wrong types to the std::make_pair template. Just change

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("int8_t", vp_int8));
```

Into

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>(std::string("int8_t"), vp_int8));
```

(note the `std::make_pair<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>` part)

EDIT: or don't provide template params at all, as someone suggested in comment.

Comment: Hi, I am terribly sorry I had that error in my code earlier. However, there is still a problem. Can you please take a look again? I have updated the code and the error.

Comment: You are right. Removing the template params removes the error. However, could you kindly tell me what would be the correct template params in that case?

Comment: Its included in my answer - "<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>" are the right template params.

Comment: Actually, no; using `<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>` does not work. If you look at my question again (which I updated after I saw your answer) you will notice that I am using `<std::string, ConstDataTypePtr>` now. I am still getting the error that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mention the types in the template in make_pair function.

```
m_nameToType.insert(std::make_pair("int8_t", vp_int8));
```